# What equation describes the path of a ball tossed in the air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I am trying to understand a lecture on stationary action and got stuck right from the beginning.  The professor says if he tosses a ball in the air it will be described as  $$X(t) = (1/2)gt( T- t).$$  T is the position or time  where it lands ( he did not say ) and g is the gravitational constant.   He plots T on x axis and the y axis I assume is the height.

First of all is T a position or a time?   and I do not recognize this as the standard path formula given in textbooks.  Did he make a mistake or am I messed up here in the interpretation?

It's a one and a half hour lecture on stationary action and I get stuck in the first minute ...this does not bode well for me.

Comment: please write your equations using MathJax

Comment: Use units to determine what it is. That is: $x(t)$ is a length, which means $gtT$ needs to be a length. That will also make it obvious that you dropped a parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: I did a small edit.   Thank you .  The equation is now exactly as it appears on the board.  I am ok if 1/2 gT = velocity .  Then it becomes the standard equation

Comment: Please be more specific.  Did the professor toss the ball straight up or at an angle?  Also, pay attention to standard nomenclature.  The "X" equation you used is typically used for vertical motion, which is usually denoted by the variable "y".  Lower case "t", and upper case "T" denote time.  In addition, to avoid getting "stuck" in the first minute, it is advisable to read the appropriate chapter BEFORE the lecture.  Then and only then, ask questions during the lecture, but be forewarned: if the prof determines that you didn't read the chapter before asking questions, he willl not like it.

Comment: The term $t(T-t)$ refers to the two roots of the equation when the Ball's height is zero. That is when it is just immediately thrown upword and when it returns to the person.

Comment: @David White ...thank you.   JEB pointed out gtT  needs to be a length ...then the units worked out and it reduced to the expression I was used to seeing.  I am Ok now but don't know how to close the question exactly without deleting it.   By the way you can't always preview on YouTube.  MITCourseWare you can but not this one i.e.  "Kenneth Young: special lecture on principle of least action".  Still a good lecture so far

Comment: @Sedumjoy, I glanced briefly at a few spots in the YouTube video you mentioned.  I'm not particularly impressed with the prof's technique ... mixing nomenclature (e.g., switching "x" and "y", using "T" for "t"), "jumping around" with the commentary, etc.

Comment: @David White .   I have been struggling to understand how variational calculus is used in the principle of stationary action for a few weeks now and would not mind if anyone knows of a good presentation of this topic.  It's a little off the beaten path of standard undergraduate college physics.   If you know a good book or lecture or document for that matter please share it with me.  Thank you

Comment: @Sedumjoy, I'll have to defer to other contributors to provide that information.  My background is chemical engineering, not physics.

Comment: @Sedumjoy My undergraduate included such teachings, I wouldn't say it is off the beaten path since it is important to the subject material...though it is saved for intermediate undergraduate teachings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a known initial height $X_o$ and an initial upward velocity $v_o$ at time $t_o$, then the equation of motion in the x-axis should be $$X(t) = X_o + {v_x}_ot -(1/2)gt^2$$.  The equation of motion in the y-axis is simply $$y(t) = y_o + v_yt$$, at least until the ball hits the floor and is stopped by friction.

It's not completely clear what $T$ represents in the equation given to you by your professor.

If T is a constant, then the term $(1/2)gTt$ (because it depends linearly on time $t$) must be a tricky way to represent velocity x time.  So, I'd guess that the initial upward velocity ${v_x}_o$ is equal to $(1/2)gT$.  Because there is not a term that does not depend on $t$, I'd guess that the ball starts out at $x_o=0$.

You should be able to plug in the values for ${v_x}_o$ and $x_o$ to get the correct answer.  The equation will have two unknown constants: $T$ and ${v_y}_o$.